# Java & C++ project integration

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I've developed a Java project and a C++ project in Netbeans. The Java project runs the exe created by the C++ project. This is working fine, but there's an awkwardness in that I hard-coded the relative path to the exe in the Java. so the question:

Is there a way I can specify the path to the exe in the Java project? The goal is to use a Java Installer, e.g., Inno Setup 5.5, to make a single installation exe that carries along the C++ exe as well as the Java project jar file?

Thanks in advance.

Ed S

Comment: Maybe a configuration file read at run time, or a batch script that supplies a command line argument.

Comment: I can see that this would work, but I was hoping to be able to have the Java application installer put the c++ exe file where it needs to be.

Comment: Oh, if you're asking "How do I make my installer do that" then my answer is "I dunno."  You might want to re-phrase your question a little, since this is primarily a programming oriented forum.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear  "... specify the path to the exe in the Java PROJECT" and in the second paragraph I say  my goal is get an installer to handle it. To me, it's all programming :-)